# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-statemachine==0.7.0

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a statemachine in python. I found python-statemachine package makes it a little easy for doing it. However, trying to install it gives the following error:

```
Collecting python-statemachine

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000383ED30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/python-statemachine/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000383EB38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/python-statemachine/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000383EC18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/python-statemachine/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000383EBA8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/python-statemachine/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000383E550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/python-statemachine/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-statemachine (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-statemachine
```

Some other info:

- OS: Windows 7, Python : 3.7.2, pip : 18.1
- Command used: pip install python-statemachine==0.7.1
- Sitting behind a proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Google results](https://www.decalage.info/en/proxy_git_pip). I do not have a proxy so I cannot confirm if this works.

```
pip
The proxy needs to be provided on the command line each time you run pip, as follows:

pip install --proxy http://proxyserver:port <package>
If you need authentication:

pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port <package>
```